# Netbeans OpenOffice Plugin throw error

Tags: java, netbeans, openoffice.org

I am using Netbeans plugin to create OO based Project, on Clicking *Finish* it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openoffice.extensions.config.LibraryManager.getLibraryName(LibraryManager.java:162)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.config.ConfigurationSettings.getLibraryName(ConfigurationSettings.java:266)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.util.ProjectCreator.updateWizardDescriptor(ProjectCreator.java:205)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.util.ProjectCreator.createAddon(ProjectCreator.java:156)
    at org.openoffice.extensions.projecttemplates.addon.AddOnWizardIterator.instantiate(AddOnWizardIterator.java:132)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1046)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:605)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:439)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:248)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:160)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1590)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1531)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2200(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
[catch] at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2171)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2229)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$11.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1454)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1499)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1900(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2236)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:458)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4279)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4209)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2128)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:1049)
    at java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Dialog.java:1101)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1099)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1076)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1126)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1098)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:128)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:273)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1083)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1615)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1567)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:846)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:984)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:186)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

I am using NB 7.2 on MACOSX